# How can I create a vertical accordion menu with smooth Javascript transitions?

Tags: javascript, menu, accordion

I am currently attempting to create a vertical accordion menu that can slide open and closed smoothly using Javascript.

Currently the javascript code I have been using looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".btn1").click(function(){
    $(".expand1").slideToggle('slow', "swing", function () {
  });
});

$(".btn2").click(function(){
  $(".expand2").slideToggle('slow', "swing", function () {
   });
});
```

My HTML:

```
<tr class="btn1">
   TITLE HERE
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="expand1">
   TEXT GOES HERE   
</td>
</tr>
```

But I have found that this code makes for a very choppy opening and closing transition.

Is there another code out there that will allow for a smoother transition?

Comment: Egads. You don't want to have to create a function for each element. Give them all the same class (the intended purpose of classes) and use one function.

Comment: Please add your HTML.

Comment: You'll have less sloppy animations by speeding them. Replace 'slow' by something like 300ms, and you should get better results.

Comment: Anyway, it's a better practice to use CSS for those kind of animations. If you're not bound by legacy browser compatibility you should give it a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be want something like that.

```js
jQuery(".box h1").click(function(){ 
 if ( jQuery(this).parent().hasClass("open") ) 
 {
  jQuery(".box").removeClass("open");
 }
 else 
 {
  jQuery(".box").removeClass("open");
  jQuery(this).parent().addClass("open");
 }
});
```

```css
#accordeon {
  width:300px;
  background:red;
  }

.box {
  max-height:50px;
  text-align:center;
  overflow:hidden;
  transition: all 1s;
  }

.box.open {
  max-height:500px;
  }

.box h1 {
  height:50px;
  line-height:50px;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  }

.box p {
  padding: 50px 0;
  background: green;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="accordeon">
  <div class="box">
    <h1> Title </h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="box">
    <h1> Title </h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
</div>
```